# Excel vba - save as pdf and vba ftp upload - upload looks funny

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

Hi I really can't get my head around this. I have a code in vba that saves the active sheet as pdf. This is working the pdf looks good! Then the code goes on, and it makes a script and then uploads the pdf to the server. The upload also works but, when I then open the file on the server 99% of the text is not there. I have tried uploading the file manually, that got created from the script and that works. So what is going on? How can the ftp script just remove 99% of the text from the pdf when it uploads it? I have also tried not to use active sheet and also set a timer, in case the files was not finished with getting created. but that is not the problem. It feels like the upload converts the pdf can this be true?
Hope somebody have a good answer.

UPDATE ! - code is now working

Here is the code I use:

```
 '''create pdf File
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Course_rates_print1").Select

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\rates-now.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False




Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"))

 ''''''''write script.dat and upload.dat file
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\script.dat", True)
a.writeline "username" 
a.writeline "password"
a.writeline "Binary"
a.writeline "mput E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\rates-now.pdf" 'file to be uploaded
a.writeline "quit"
a.Close

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\upload.bat", True)
a.writeline "ftp -i -s:E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\script.dat 
ftp.server" 'the ftp site
a.Close


dRetVal = Shell("E:\Kunder-i-brug\PSC\office-software\upload.bat", 0) 
'upload the file
 ''''''''''end upload.bat file

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Are you performing a binary transfer?  http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#binary

Comment: Good question! The code you see is the code that I use. But it sounds like you are directing me in the right direction. I will try to find out, if this is the problem. I'm not so in to the use of .bat and script or use ftp with vba, so it could be :)

Comment: You are a star. Got it to work :)
Added the line
`a.writeline "Binary"`
after the pasword - can you post it as an answer so I can close this :) and thank you for you help Tim.

Comment: btw, if you use a .ftp extension on your script, you can simply execute the script.ftp and standard file association will run it under ftp.exe script.ftp.